# How to get project badge via GitHub API?

Tags: api, github, github-api, badge

I have build a resume page for my self, and list all my projects there by using GitHub API. Some of the project are document which have `rtfd build passing` badge, some are python projects which have travis-ci and pep-lint badges.

Now, I want to display the badges as with the projects, how should I use with the API?

My page is here: http://gh.windrunner.info/resume/#/github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For projects like https://github.com/kxxoling/z42-doc (which does have a badge in it), you need to fetch the README and then search through it for possible badges. Without knowing what language you'd prefer to use, I'm going to write some pseudo-code

First you need to retrieve the README that GitHub identified as the one to render on your home-page. You can do this by doing

```
 GET /repos/kxxoling/z42-doc/readme
 Host: https://api.github.com
 Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw
```

If instead you'd rather parse HTML, change "raw" to "html" in the last header, e.g.,

```
 GET /repos/kxxoling/z42-doc/readme
 Host: https://api.github.com
 Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.html
```

With the contents of the README, now you just need to parse it for links or directives that are specific to the mark-up languages you chose for your READMEs. You can parse them out with regular expressions or an HTML/XML parsing library of your choosing (if you're retrieving the rendered content from GitHub).

Comment: It seems practicable, but seems I have to send a network request and parse the response in browser for every repo, not that elegant I think.

Comment: @kxxoling not everything has to be done in the browser. If you're generating your repository listing that way, then I'm surprised that you're adverse to doing this. If your repository listing is auto-generated on the server and otherwise static, you can get this when you generate the repository listing. You should really only have to do this once or twice a day if you make it a cron job

Answer (score 6):

You could also use a different API with https://github-shields.com/

See "[How to embed live Github PR status in your blogs & docs](https://blog.starkandwayne.com/2014/12/30/live-github-pr-status-in-your-blogs-docs/)"

> Consider the PR https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh/pull/715.
>   The URL doesn't indicate if the PR is open/merged/closed.
>
> The `cloudfoundry/bosh/pull/715` portion of the URL is copied directly into the following base URL:
>
> `https://github-shields.com/github/ + cloudfoundry/bosh/pull/715 + .svg` gives a URL that redirects to the PR.
>
> https://github-shields.com/github/cloudfoundry/bosh/pull/715.svg
>
> As an image URL it gives `cloudfoundry/bosh/pull/715`
>
> Awesome, it was merged!

---

For the status of a project, the [OP kxxoling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836912/kxxoling) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804771/how-to-get-project-badge-via-github-api/28805165#comment45926241_28805165) having found [**shields.io**](http://shields.io/):

```
https://img.shields.io/badge/<SUBJECT>-<STATUS>-<COLOR>.svg
```

> it indicates how to get the status of a badge.
>   If there none badge added for that project, it will return a inaccessible badge like this: https://img.shields.io/travis/kxxoling/z42-doc.svg => [image: inaccessible]

Comment: From the link I found this: http://shields.io/ , it indicates how to get the status of a badge, if there none badge added for that project, it will return a inaccecable badge like this: https://img.shields.io/travis/kxxoling/z42-doc.svg . I will have a deeper look at later after finishing work.

Comment: @kxxoling Looks good! I have included that link in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: But how can I know which badges a project has? That's what I want but not a "inaccessible badge".

Comment: @kxxoling which badges? If each badge is related to a status or a PR status, the question should be how to get those status.

Comment: I have a list of repos r1, r2, r3... For each of them, if it has badge1, it shows  badge1 in the list page, if it has badge2, shows badge2... So that I can ignore which kind of repo they are, and shows all the related badges beside.

Comment: @kxxoling that I don't know. Unless the process is scripted and able to detect those badges, I don't think there is a feature which does exactly what you want.

Comment: OK..Really thanks for you help!  I may have to write a script to parse the README file like sigmavirus24 mentioned.